# Their mistake or mine?

Tags: grid-deduction, nonogram

I've found [Pepper's Puzzles](https://store.steampowered.com/app/642650/Peppers_Puzzles/) to be a very nice introduction to picross puzzles, with a cute anime girl to boot.  While I've steadily improved in my deductive powers and the logic inherent to nonograms, this puzzle, half-solved, has me stymied.

After my normal minor temper tantrum, I took a breath.  This game was programmed by one person.  It's not impossible one of the dozens upon dozens of puzzles has a mistake.  Or maybe I errored in the first part of the solve: I do make plenty of mistakes.  So, what am I missing, if anything?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First thing I noticed:**

Assuming all correct so far (I've not re-done the puzzle, just looking at current state), the second to bottom row could be:

```
#####xx##xx###x...x##xxx
or
#####xx##xx###xxxxxx#x##
```

Either way there's an extra 'x' that can be marked (in the column with 1 7 1)

That column has a 7 above a 1, and the extra 'x' means the block for the 1 can be placed, and more blocks from the 7 become certain...

**Second thing, and perhaps more useful:**

Looking at it on its own, the '5' at the far right can be in two different distinct positions...

However, if it were in the lower of the 2 positions, that immediately creates a contradiction, as it forces more than 3 consecutive cells to be highlighted in the second-to-right column. Therefore it must be in the top half of the grid.

This directly implies a stronger form of the first thing I noticed, and several other cascading implications.

Following through with that I was able to complete the puzzle yielding the following grid:

> [image]

So it seems that nobody made a mistake - your solution so far was correct, and the puzzle was solvable.

**Solving using only "simple logic"**

> The column with 1 7 1 forces an additional square to be shaded - you perhaps mis-counted how many squares were forced.
>  
>  This additional square is one that would have to be blank for the 2 3 2 from its row to all fit in the same wide gap, therefore that row must have the final 2 at the far right.
>  
>  That then indicates which gap the '5' fits into without calling on the logic given above, and the rest of the puzzle will fall into place as before.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'll have to keep in mind that there's a sort of two-possibility if-then logic tactic that these puzzles might sometimes require.

Comment: @Exal Reviewing the puzzle again, this second-level logic wasn't REQUIRED. I'll add an extra section to my answer to explain that.